# $.post function doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function saveMe() {
    var strValues = "";
    var boxLength = document.choiceForm.choiceBox.length;
    var count = 0;
    if (boxLength != 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < boxLength; i++) {
            if (count == 0) {
                strValues = document.choiceForm.choiceBox.options[i].value;

            }
            else {
                strValues = strValues + "," + document.choiceForm.choiceBox.options[i].value;
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (strValues.length == 0) {
        alert("You have not made any selections");
    }
    else {
        $.post("rolGridPermition.php", {
            rolId: strValues
        });
    }
}​
```

in this code $.post function between else paranthesis does not work... is there any problem? can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you attempted to find a solution, or work out _why_ it doesn't work? Check your browser's error console and make sure the PHP script it sends to actually functions.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: this is the problem? what does mean... I am new in php & js

Comment: Then there's your error. Change the path of `rolGridPermition.php` by adding a directory or something; the AJAX request is making the server look for a file that isn't there.

Comment: Try console.log(strValue) to make sure whether it's being populated or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use the url properly,

```
$.post("http://yourdomain/rolGridPermition.php", {rolId: strValues }, function(data) {
    // code here
});
```

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)** means the php file is not in the server or url is not correct.

Comment: 404(not found) error was because of a .css file... also i tried the full path ... but it didnt work.. :(

Comment: What result do you expect from the server as the response of $.post request ? Have you echoed anything inside your php ile and have you added a callback function to process the response ?

Comment: it is passing a parameter as you see...  in rolGridPermition.php this parameter will  record in database...but  it is not passing

Answer (score 0):

If you have jQuery included in your script, this should work.

```
$.post("rolGridPermition.php", {  rolId: strValues},function(result){
   alert(result);
});
```

Keep in mind that you can not make a call to a page in a different domain because of the cross domain policy. Still you can do some hacks to get it done ( using jspnp as datatype)